# Length of the tracks array in radar_msgs/RadarTrackArray

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having this programming problem in ROS.

I'm looping through the tracks array in radar_msgs/RadarTrackArray message and accessing its values. I'm using for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(msg->tracks)/sizeof(msg->tracks[0]); i++)
```

But this expression for getting the array length returns the value of 0 all the time, although the tracks contains different number of tracks. sizeof(msg->tracks) returns the value of 24 and sizeof(msg->tracks[0]) returns the value of 80 all the time.

How do I fix this to get correct array length?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321354/length-of-the-tracks-array-in-radar_msgs/radartrackarray/) by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm using for-loop:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(msg->tracks)/sizeof(msg->tracks[0]); i++)
> ```

Don't do this. This is (almost) how you *could* calculate the number of elements in an array in C.

`roscpp` is all C++, so there is no need for this (and it also won't (always) work).

This is the structure of a [radar_msgs/RadarTrackArray](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/radar_msgs/html/msg/RadarTrackArray.html):

```
std_msgs/Header header
radar_msgs/RadarTrack[] tracks
```

`tracks` is a unbounded array (or list). In `roscpp`, those will be mapped onto `std::vector` (see [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification)).

C++ provides a few convenient ways to iterate over `std::vector`:

1. a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (if you can use C++11)
2. regular iteration [using iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/)
3. element-wise access using the `[]` operator (and bounded by `std::vector::size()`)

You tagged this question with `kinetic`, so I'm going to assume you are on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04). That version of Ubuntu ships with GCC 5.4, so you should be able to enable C++11. Range-based for loops are pretty convenient, so I would recommend to use those.

If you require a counter, use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg->tracks.size(); i++)
{
  [...]
}
```

---

Edit: I was curious to see whether range-based for loops and counting could be combined (just as in Python with `enumerate(..)`). If you can use C++17, it turns out you can do that: [Python-Like enumerate() In C++17](http://reedbeta.com/blog/python-like-enumerate-in-cpp17/). That should allow you to do something like:

```
for (auto [i, track] : enumerate(msg->tracks))
{
  // do something with 'i' and/or 'track'
}
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-18**:
Note also that this is a pure C++ question. Not something specific to ROS.

**Comment by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on 2019-04-18**:
Thank you for your answer and sorry for the question related to c++.
As this tracks is an unbounded array, it is not actually favorable. Although we are interested in a small number of objects, we may have to loop through a large size of tracks array.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-19**:\

> Thank you for your answer and sorry for the question related to c++.

No need to apologise. I just wanted to make you aware of the fact that this is not something ROS specific, but a generic C++ question (ie: you don't need to limit yourself to ROS specific support fora).

> As this tracks is an unbounded array, it is not actually favorable.

I'm not sure I understand this comment.

Your initial for-loop approach would have iterated over the exact same array (well, `std::vector`), there is no functional difference.

**Comment by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on 2019-04-19**:
Your help is much appreciated. I didn't know the tracks array is unbounded and this is where I was confused although I was using the msg->tracks.size(). Regarding the question that I made you confused, I just posted another question here. https://answers.ros.org/question/321461/loop-through-unbounded-tracks-array-in-radar_msgsradartrackarray/